# make_ext4fs: command not found, in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I need to create system.img file from a mounted folder, found make_ext4 command method in online, but it shows "make_ext4fs: command not found" in ubuntu 22.04.

Then I tried running "sudo apt-get install android-tools-fsutils", but got error "E: Package 'android-tools-fsutils' has no installation candidate"

Please help.

Comment: Where are you getting your instructions from?, Ubuntu has `mkfs.ext4` & other standard GNU/Linux tools built in, where you appear to be expecting to use *modified* tools created for Android & other OSes based on the standard tools you're trying to avoid?

Comment: Okay, but I found guide with make_ext4fs,
However, please give an example to create system.img from a folder content using **mkfs.ext4** command.

Comment: @MdHafeez are you satisfied with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

`android-tools-fsutils` is an old package (see this [doc](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=android-tools-fsutils) from Debian Buster, which was the basis of Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.10). This package is not available in Ubuntu 22.04. You should use `mkfs -t ext4` instead (provided by the Ubuntu 22.04 package `makefs`.

`make_ext4fs` is not maintained by Android any more and has been deleted from their codebase (see this [commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/a15ff357b13c3dcc1d9a468c8540b2bcfcc1b567)). In Android, it has been replaced by mke2fs, which is available in Ubuntu 22.04 with the package `android-sdk-platform-tools` which installs `/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/mke2fs` (this path is not in the default `PATH`).

You can create an ext4 image and add the content of a directory to the image using `mkfs -t ext4` by following e.g. the instructions in this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1688983/212280) which uses a loop mount.